# Ubuntu/Nvidia lists DVI dual cable as single

Tags: ubuntu, dvi, external-display, nvidia-quadro

I have an NVidia Quadro FX 880M graphics card, from which I am trying to drive 2 monitors: my internal laptop montior (15.6", 1920x1080, Nvidia driver says it's running via DisplayPort) and an external 27" monitor (Dell U2711, 2560x1440 native resolution, via DVI).

I've hooked the dual DVI cable to the dual DVI port on my dock (Dell PR03X) and installed the proprietary NVidia driver, but I cannot seem to get the full 2560x1440 out of the larger 27" external monitor. Looking at the NVidia driver settings, the monitor's connection is reported as a single DVI cable, rather than a dual one, which would explain the reduced resolution.

Does anyone have any experience with an issue like this? What can I do to make full use of my new monitor?

(Possibly) Relevant Information:

- There is no DVI port on the laptop itself, but one is provided via the dock.
- The laptop and dock both provide a DisplayPort jack, but I have been unable to get this working on either w/ the monitor.
- I did have the nouveau driver installed when I installed the nvidia proprietary driver, but have since removed it (no change in the monitor situation when I removed it).
- The 27" reports a max resolution of 1680x1050.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: What does Windows report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that you have the full DVI cable. Some DVI cables have pins missing and the higher resolutions or higher refresh rates require them all.

Comment: Also verify that you the Quadro FX 880M exposes a DVI-D port (dual link)